# Awaiting Associate Editor decision MEAN?

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors, open-access, review-articles

I had submitted a paper in a reputed journal in more than 2 months back. Upto one month the status was " manuscript is assigned to the editor"  Now, the status of the paper is showing "Awaiting Associate Editor decision". Please, tell what does this status indicates? Is all the reviewers process has been done??